# Take screenshot of iOS device by code (not swift or xamarin)

Tags: c#, ios, bitmap, screenshot, ranorex

I'm working on verifying screen of the iOS app by using tesseract engine (OCR).
I'm using Ranorex (Test automation tool) that use .net 4.5 frame.

```
MobileApp targetApp = repo.App;
    Bitmap actualImage = Imaging.CaptureImage(targetApp,0,true);
```

I used above code to get a bitmap of the current screen. However, the resolution is too low to run OCR. Therefore, I need to work on the other ways.

1st: If Ranorex has some function that takes high resolution of the screen image.

2nd: If there is c#(.net frame 4.5) code that can get high resolution of the screen image.

3rd: Find a tool to take a screen shot of iPad app (external tool), and save all high resolution screen shot first, and read the file by bitmap(C:\xxxx).

It would be great if I can get a good suggestion.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Apple locked down the API (IOSurface) that you used to be able to use to get a screen-shot of the entire device screen in iOS 9. Now it's only possible to capture images of your app's contents, not system-drawn components or other apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can take screenshots using the UIAutomation framework from Apple.

You can use this code to generate screen shots:

target.captureScreenWithName("HomeScreen");